# How to interchange array keys and values using for loop?

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I have an array like

```
$a = array('1'=>'one','2'=>'two','3'=>'three');
```

I want to interchange key and value with each other using only for loop, and i want desired output like

```
$a = array('one'=>1,'two'=>2,'three'=>3);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using a foreach loop:

```
 <?php 

    $a = array('1'=>'one','2'=>'two','3'=>'three');

    $tmp = array();

    foreach($a as $key=>$value){
        $tmp[$value] = $key;

    }

?>
```

Comment: could u make it with for loop?

Comment: $a = array('1'=>'one','2'=>'two','3'=>'three');

 
 $tmp = array();
 for($i=1; $i<=count($a); $i++){

  $tmp[array_search($a[$i], $a)] = $a[$i]; 
 
 }

Answer (score 5):

Use [`array_flip`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php):

```
$a = array('one'=>1,'two'=>2,'three'=>3);
$a_flipped = array_flip($a);
```

---

If you insist on using a loop, then create a new empty array, iterate through the given array and fill the new array using values as keys, i.e.:

```
$a = array('one'=>1,'two'=>2,'three'=>3);
$a_flipped = array();
foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
    $a_flipped[$value] = $key;
}
```

Comment: i want do this with for loop not with array function.

Comment: @user3056158, although I can't see any reasons of using a loop rather than a built-in function, I edited the answer and included the loop solution.